# How to get identity of SignalR connected users which are using client mvc application with owin authentication?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

In my solution, I have 2 projects : **SignalRServer**, **WebClient** which are both **MVC application**.
In my server, I've used **SignalR 2 Hub** and in client project I've used **jquery SignalR** library to connect to hub server by passing hosted server url as hub connection url.

Everything is working as well and client can receive messages from server.

The problem : In client project I have added authentication and users must enter their username and password to view the page which messages are going to be viewed.
Now I want to get the signed in username which has connected to **SignalR Hub Server** and send related messages to each user using this username.

How do I know which user has connected to server while the authentication is processing in client project separated from server project ?

**JQuery client hub:**

```
var PbxHub = $.connection.pbxhub;

$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:10437/signalr";
$.connection.hub.logging = true;

$.connection.hub.start({
    jsonp: true,
    withCredentials: false
}).done(function () {
    console.log('Hub is connected.');
});

$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    console.log('Hub is disconnected.');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 1500); // Restart connection after 1500 miliseconds.
});
```

**Client Startup:**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
    });
}
```

**Server Startup:**

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            };

            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
```

Appreciated for any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by Microsoft documentation at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cookie-authentication

> In a browser-based app, cookie authentication allows your existing
>   user credentials to automatically flow to SignalR connections. When
>   using the browser client, no additional configuration is needed. If
>   the user is logged in to your app, the SignalR connection
>   automatically inherits this authentication.

So, by using same DBContext which used in client app , I could access to connectionId of users which connected to hub and either insert records to database after sending them messages.

```
    if (_context.Extension.Any(ex=>ex.Code.ToString() == deviceName))
    {
        extensionID = _context.Extension.SingleOrDefault(ex => ex.Code.ToString() == deviceName).ID.ToString();
    }
    else { return; }

    asterHub.Clients.User(extensionID).SendState(
            e.Device_state.Name,
            string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",
                pc.GetHour(DateTime.Now),
                pc.GetMinute(DateTime.Now),
                pc.GetSecond(DateTime.Now)),
            state,
            stateCode);
```